# Form is not submited if using onclick event + javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to disable the submit button for 5 seconds before it becomes clickable. The script works and make the button unclickable for 5 second, but the problem is it doesn't submit the form.

Please help.

```
<form id="frm_wanted_search">
<input type="submit" onclick="lockoutSubmit(this)" name="school_name" id="btn_book_search" value="Search">
</form>

<script>
function lockoutSubmit(button) {
var oldValue = button.value;

button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
button.value = '...processing...';

setTimeout(function(){
    button.value = oldValue;
    button.removeAttribute('disabled');
 }, 5000) }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
<form name ="form1" id="frm_wanted_search">
<input type="submit" onclick="lockoutSubmit(this)" name="school_name" id="btn_book_search" value="Search">
</form>

<script>
function lockoutSubmit(button) {

event.preventDefault();
var oldValue = button.value;

button.value = '...processing...';

setTimeout(function(){
button.value = oldValue;


document.form1.submit();
 }, 5000) 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the idea is you bind the page load event, do some stuff on the button, and trigger a timer on it.

```js
window.onload = disableButton;

var button = document.getElementById("btn_book_search");
var oldValue = button.value;

function disableButton() {  
  button.value = '...processing...';
  button.disabled = true;
  setTimeout(function(){
    button.value = oldValue;
    button.removeAttribute('disabled');
 }, 5000);
}
```

```html
<form id="frm_wanted_search">
<input type="submit" name="school_name" id="btn_book_search" value="Search">
</form>
```